# How can I left join A with B and also right join B with C at one time?

Tags: mysql, database

I have three A, B, C tables.

How can I left join A with B and also right join B with C at one time?

For example If I have these tables: Order, Product, User, I want be like this query:

```
SELECT Product.title, User.username, Order.id
FROM Order
/* relations: */
Order LEFT JOIN Product
Product RIGHT JOIN User
/* with this condition: */
ON Order.ProductID = Product.ID
ON Product.UserID = User.ID
```

Comment: So what is your intended result? Is it _all_ rows from `A` and _all_ rows from `C`, with only those rows in `B` related to _either_ `A` or `C`?

Comment: I'm not seeing the purpose of the right join against `C`, when a `UserOD` doesn't have a relation back to `Order` without an intervening `Product`.

Comment: It never hurts to describe the tables involved and the intended result in your questions. Thus we can find more accurate solutions to your issue.
About joins, a short reading for you [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but to get your above syntax to work properly, try this:

```
SELECT Product.title, User.username, Order.id
FROM Order
    LEFT JOIN Product
         ON Order.ProductID = Product.ID
    RIGHT JOIN User
         ON Product.UserID = User.ID
```

Depending on your desired results, I prefer using `LEFT JOINs` for readability -- so if you want all users, regardless if they are in the product table or order table, then this would work:

```
SELECT U.username, P.title, O.id
FROM User U
    LEFT JOIN Product P
         ON P.UserId = U.Id
    LEFT JOIN Order O
         ON O.ProductID = P.ID
```